# When to use bmesh.update_edit_mesh and when Mesh.update?

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh

When is it appropriate to use one over the other?

In example, I have the following:

```
obj = bpy.data.objects[name]
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
dmesh = obj.data
mesh = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(dmesh)
# do stuff with mesh
#
# call one or the other:
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(dmesh)
dmesh.update()
```

Which call is correct in the end?

In my tests they seem to do the same.

Comment: The example is slightly misleading in that dmesh may not necessarily be context.object.data, that said I'd say the rule of thumb is use bmesh.update_edit_mesh() when you are using bmesh and mesh.update() when you are not.

Comment: @batFINGER: thanks, I have updated the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The mesh data used by an object is stored within [`object.data`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.data), the most obvious data being stored within the [`vertices`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.vertices), [`edges`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.edges) and [`polygons`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.polygons) properties.

When you add or alter `edges` or `polygons` you need to use [`object.data.update()`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.update) to see the changes in the 3dview.

To see this working, start with a default cube in wireframe shading and enter the following into a python console.

```
odata = bpy.data.objects['Cube'].data
odata.edges[8].vertices[0] = 3
odata.edges[8].vertices[1] = 5
```

You shouldn't see any difference yet, now enter

```
odata.update()
```

and you will see one of the edges is now across the top face and not on the side.

Instead of directly editing the mesh data, it is preferred to use the extra functionality provided in the bmesh module. The function [`bmesh.from_edit_mesh()`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.html#bmesh.from_edit_mesh) makes a copy of the mesh data that you can make changes to while the object is in edit mode, the changes you make remain in this copy until you call [`bmesh.update_edit_mesh()`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.html#bmesh.update_edit_mesh), this lets you add 10,000 faces and then do one refresh to reduce the amount of drawing/copying needed. If you directly alter the object data while the object is in edit mode then those changes will be lost as the bmesh edit_mesh will overwrite any changes upon exiting edit mode.

Similar to `bmesh.from_edit_mesh()` and `bmesh.update_edit_mesh()` we also have [`bm.from_mesh()`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMesh.from_mesh) and [`bm.to_mesh()`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMesh.to_mesh) which allow us to edit the mesh data while the object remains in object mode. (these are available after `bm = bmesh.new()`)

Comment: So, does `bmesh.update_edit_mesh(odata)` implies an `odata.update()`?

Comment: No, the edit mesh is separate from `odata`, but exiting edit mode transfers the edit mesh to `odata`, then does `odata.update()`. The `update_edit_mesh()` is just to update the edit mode viewport display. If you use `from_mesh()` it doesn't alter `odata` until you use `to_mesh()` which then also updates.